# Can't access ng-repeat's variable from a directive inside it

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

So I have this in my view:

```
<tr ng-repeat="currentRow in rowsToRender">
<td>{{currentRow[0]}}</td>
<div rmx-schedule-row time="currentRow" time-from="{{currentRow[0]}}" time-to="{{currentRow[1]}}" date="{{dateStr}}"/>
</tr>
```

And the directive:

```
rmx.directive('rmxScheduleRow', function(scheduleService) {
      return {
          scope: {
              time: "=",
              date: "@",
              timeFrom: "@",
              timeTo: "@"
          },
         controller: [
             "$scope", "$rootScope", "$element", "$attrs", "$http",
             function($scope, $rootScope, $elm, $attrs, $http) {
                 $attrs.$observe('timeFrom', function(val) {
                     console.log("change has been detected");
                     console.log($scope);
                     console.log($attrs);
                     console.log(val);
                 });
             }
         ]
     };
 });
```

In the view, currentRow[0] is evaluated properly and prints what it's expected to.

But in the directive, currentRow[0] and [1] are interpolated to empty string ("") and the object `time` is interpolated to undefined. And I'm going insane from trying to spot a typo or something :(

I tried `$scope.$watch` with the same results.

Comment: if you have currentrow what is the need to pass currentrow[0] and currentrow[1] .Kindly share your complete code with rowstorender object or just setup a plunker demo

Comment: If the code is copy/pasted, your inner `<div>` is not closed - `</div>`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use $parse service for parsing your variables of scope from directive.

```
time = $parse(attr.currentRow)($scope)
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the `<div>` within the table is a typo, which is causing the interpolation to silently fail.  Replace that with `<td></td>`, and you win:

[Working plunk](http://plunker.co/edit/W20lxAGBFE0ohvL0V2Hh)

Or perhaps you meant to wrap the div within the table cell:

```
<td>Stuff
    <div></div>
</td>
```